# Assign id according to conditions plus maximum number of observations in r

Tags: r

I have the following data:

| code | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 1 | d |
| 1 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | f |
| 3 | f |
| 3 | g |
| 3 | h |
| 4 | i |
| 4 | j |
| 4 | k |
| 4 | l |
| 4 | l |
| 4 | m |

I want to assing an id for each case with matching "code" and "name" so I used the following code:

```
data %>%
mutate(id=group_indices(data,.dots=c("code", "name")))
```

This works well and gives the following result:

| code | name | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 |
| 1 | c | 3 |
| 1 | d | 4 |
| 1 | d | 4 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 3 | f | 6 |
| 3 | f | 6 |
| 3 | g | 7 |
| 3 | h | 8 |
| 4 | i | 9 |
| 4 | j | 10 |
| 4 | k | 11 |
| 4 | l | 12 |
| 4 | l | 12 |

Yet, I need something extra, I know  that no more than 7 observations with match "code" and "name" can have to the same "id", and I would like id to reflect this. This would mean that row 14 would have id = 6 instead of 5 and will be different from row 7-13 even though they share the same "code" and "name" values.

Can the "id" be different when a maximum number of rows sharing values is achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `ceiling` and `row_number` to create the "observation group" `obs_group`.

```r
 df %>%
  group_by(code, name) %>%
  mutate(obs_group = ceiling(row_number()/7)) %>%
  group_by(code, name, obs_group) %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id())
#> # A tibble: 24 x 4
#> # Groups:   code, name, obs_group [14]
#>     code name  obs_group    id
#>    <int> <chr>     <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1 a             1     1
#>  2     1 a             1     1
#>  3     1 b             1     2
#>  4     1 c             1     3
#>  5     1 d             1     4
#>  6     1 d             1     4
#>  7     2 e             1     5
#>  8     2 e             1     5
#>  9     2 e             1     5
#> 10     2 e             1     5
#> 11     2 e             1     5
#> 12     2 e             1     5
#> 13     2 e             1     5
#> 14     2 e             2     6
#> 15     3 f             1     7
#> 16     3 f             1     7
#> 17     3 g             1     8
#> 18     3 h             1     9
#> 19     4 i             1    10
#> 20     4 j             1    11
#> 21     4 k             1    12
#> 22     4 l             1    13
#> 23     4 l             1    13
#> 24     4 m             1    14
```

---

Data

```
df <- structure(list(code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                              2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), name = c("a", 
                                                                                              "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
                                                                                              "f", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "l", "m")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      -24L))
```